# Create Multiple Products in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on magento using `Magento 1.X API`. I want to create products in magento so I'm using `catalogProductCreate` method to create.

This is working great when it is around `5 to 10 products`, but when trying to insert  multiple products it is taking a lot of time.

Is there any method to insert bulk products at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The API/programmatic/dataflow method of adding products in Magento is notoriously slow when dealing with large data sets.

If you haven't already looked at it, try Magmi - it is the missing piece of Magento catalogue management.  You can add/update thousands of products in minutes with spreadsheets.  It can also be called on CLI which opens up lots of excellent automation possibilities.

Oh, and best of all - it's free.

https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this code to add/update products on Magento.

```
<?php
include_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$counter = 0;
```

I have this function to get (or create) a product by SKU:

```
function GetProduct($sku)
{
    global $counter;
    echo $sku;
    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId = $p -> getIdBySku($sku);       
    if($productId)
    {
        echo "!";
        $p -> load( $productId );
    }
    else
    {
        $p->setTypeId('simple');
        $p->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); 
        $p->setStatus(1);
        $p->setTaxClassId(7);
        $p->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); 
        $p->setStoreIDs(array(1)); 
        $p->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $p->setSku($sku);
    }
    echo "...";
    $counter++;
    echo " ".$counter;
    return $p;
}
```

Here's the function to save the product:

```
function SaveProduct($p)
{
    try
    {
        if (is_array($errors = $p->validate()))
        {
            $strErrors = array();
            foreach($errors as $code=>$error)
            {
                $strErrors[] = ($error === true)? Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute "%s" is invalid.', $code) : $error;
                echo $strErrors[0];
            }
            $this->_fault('data_invalid', implode("\n", $strErrors));
        }
        $p->save();
        echo "\n";
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e)
    {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And finally I'm calling like this:

```
$product = GetProduct('sku1');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku1');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku2');
$product->setData('url_path', 'plastic-hat.html');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku3');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku3');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku4');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku4');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('sku5');
$product->setData('thumbnail_label', 'sku5');
SaveProduct($product);
unset($product);
```

I run this code from the command-line as there is a memory leak running it this way. You can only get so many products updated before it blows the memory and you have to edit and re-run the code to keep going, but it works and it's relatively fast.